# How to mark proactive message a s IMPORTANT

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a bot application that sends **proactive** messages in the channel as adaptive cards. Below is the piece of the code responsible for creating the proactive messages.

```
adapter.continueConversationAsync(
   botid, 
   {reference },
   async (turnContext) => {
      await turnContext.sendActivities([Adaptive card body]);
   }
)
```

**Question:** Is there a way how we can mark the message as **IMPORTANT!** like below:

[image]

Comment: Currently we do not support sending important messages with bots.
To achieve your requirements, we recommend you give your feedback in Teams [UserVoice](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).
Microsoft will always focus on customer’s feedback and experience. Some new features would be added to the services based on customers' feedback in the future, and your good ideas will be very helpful for them to improve the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more visibility, adding the answer from the comment section:

Currently we do not support sending important messages with bots.

You can please share your feedback in Microsoft Teams [Feedback Portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).

Microsoft will always focus on customer’s feedback and experience.
Some new features would be added to the services based on customers' feedback in the future, and your good ideas will be very helpful for them to improve the service.